# Majority of my column headers are dates in my dataframe, not able to use the loc function - how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that shows the number of downloads for each show, where every month is a column, with the actual start of each month being the data column name.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/TestUser/Documents/Folder/Test.xlsx', sheet_name='Downloads', header=2)
df
```

df looks like this below:

| Show | 2017-08-01 00:00:00 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Show 1 | 23004 | 50320 | 450320 |
| Show 2 | 30418 | 74021 | 92103 |

However, when I try to access a column using the loc function, I run into an error:

```
df.loc[:, 2017-08-01 00:00:00]
```

***File "", line 1
df.loc[:, 2017-07-01 00:00:00]
^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers***

When I put single quotes before the date, I get another error:
***KeyError: '2017-07-01 00:00:00'***

The data type for the date column headers are **float64**, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert headers to string

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

or

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
```

then,
if you want to access all the column

```
df['2017-08-01 00:00:00']
```

or if you want to access for example cell 5 of this column

```
df.at[4, '2017-08-01 00:00:00']
```